# Retrieve data from a azure mobile service into a android apllication in java

Tags: java, c#, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a Azure mobile Service which retrieves data from multiple sources and delivers it for my mobile application to consume . so far I have used it in developing windows mobile application and it works completely fine .Now that I want to extend the same app to android , I want to leverage the data from the same azure mobile service .

My C# code for the Windows app to retrieve the data is

```
MobileServiceClient mobileservice = new MobileServiceClient("url", "key");
var aod_return = await mobileservice.InvokeApiAsync("CCOOutageHistoryData", HttpMethod.Get, null);
List<Data> aod_result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(aod_return.ToString());
VList3.ItemsSource = aod_result;
```

I tried using this in JAVA for the android app

```
try {
   mClient = new MobileServiceClient("url", "key", this);


   mClient.invokeApi("CCOOutageHistoryData",null, "GET", null, new ApiJsonOperationCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onCompleted(JsonElement jsonElement, Exception e, ServiceFilterResponse serviceFilterResponse) {
         GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
         Gson gson = gsonb.create();

         JsonArray array = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
         List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
            for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
               myObjects.add(gson.fromJson(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().toString(), MyObject.class));
            }
       }
   });
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   // Do nothing
}
```

However ,when I give the breakpoint , after initializing the mclient it doesnot enter to the next lines of code , and also the syntax I used for Mclient.Incokeapi is said to be deprecated . can you please point of the mistake and help me out to implement the above c# code in the new syntax in Java.

I get the below exception when I build the code.

```
invoke is not implemented
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: invoke is not implemented
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.refactoring.introduce.OCBaseIntroduceHandler.invoke(OCBaseIntroduceHandler.java:263)
    at com.intellij.refactoring.actions.BaseRefactoringAction.actionPerformed(BaseRefactoringAction.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher$3.performAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:593)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:644)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.inInitState(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:483)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:213)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:538)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I tried using

```
mClient.invokeApi("CCOOutageHistoryData",null, "GET", null, new ApiJsonOperationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JsonElement jsonElement, Exception e, ServiceFilterResponse serviceFilterResponse) {
                    GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
                    Gson gson = gsonb.create();                    JsonArray array = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
                    List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
                    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
                    {
                        myObjects.add(gson.fromJson(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().toString(), MyObject.class));
                    }
                }
            });
```

but does not work . can some one please help me fix this issue

Comment: Is this line -             `mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                    "url",
                    "key",
                    this); `in the constructor?

Comment: Yes CarbineCoder that is the constructor for MobileServiceClient ,which takes the parameters  public MobileServiceClient(String appUrl, String appKey, Context context)

Comment: Sorry if I am asking lame question , but ya when I make it MobileServiceClient("url","key") it says it cannot recognize the constructor of this format .. all the examples I have seen had mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                    "url",
                    "key",
                    this);

Comment: I think the problem is with mclient.Invokeapi , while debugging though I use a breakpoint , the code in these lines is being skipped. and I dint find the proper way if implementing the new overload of Invoke api . :(

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.mobileserviceclient.aspx from here i saw there are overloaded constructors with 2 parameters. I guess you need to call invokeApi after you have set the httpmessage handler array in that case.

Comment: but I am unable to pass only two parameters in java . its says cannot find the constructor :(

Comment: Apologies, my mistake... I thought it was C#

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, you want to using Java for Android to retrieve data from a custom API endpoint in JavaScript backend of Mobile Service, like your code in C#.

Assumption that you are familiar with C#, nto Java. I think you can try to review the javadoc of Class `MobileServiceClient` to know how to use the functions `invokeApi` with different arguments. I can't find this javadoc, but I think you can get the similar helps from the comments of the source code of Class `MobileServiceClient` at https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/android/src/sdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/MobileServiceClient.java.

Meanwhile, there are some offical tutorials and blog below that can help learning the principle.

1. [How to: define a custom API endpoint in a JavaScript backend mobile service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-define-custom-api/)
2. [The section `How to: Call a custom API` of the doc `How to use the Android client library for Mobile Services`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/#custom-api)
3. [The blog `Custom API in Azure Mobile Services – Client SDKs` from MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2013/06/18/custom-api-in-azure-mobile-services-client-sdks/)

Hope it helps. Best Regards.

---

Update:

Response content from backend like as below:

```
{"name": "peter", "age": 28}
```

The Java code as below:

```
public class Person {
   private String name;
   private int age;

   ....Getting & Setting Methods
}

// The code `Person.class` as the Class<E> clazz argument for the function invokeApi, not null
mClient.invokeApi("<controllerName>", "GET", Person.class);
```

Comment: Hi Perter , the backend is a MVC controller application hosted on azure, it is not in java script . I am looking invoking the controllers in the Mobile service from the android application

Comment: @VyshnaviReddy OK. Per my experience, if your backend can accept the same HTTP method request and response the content like the JS backend of Mobile service, such as JSON content, the `invokeApi` will works as your wish. Because the JS backend of Mobile Service also is a MVC application using express framework for NodeJS.

Comment: Got It , my backend application accepts the http requests and returns the JSON result , I have already implemented it in C#, my concern is I have tried implementing the mclient.Invokeapi("controllername","get",null) method for invoking the controller , but that's not working.for some constructors of InvokeAPi it says that they are deprecated :( it will be of great help if you can help me out with the correct syntax of doing that .

Comment: mClient.invokeApi("CCOOutageHistoryData","GET",null,MyObject.class); I have used this constructor and now I don't get any exceptions , but not sure how do I retrieve the data that is returned . sorry for bugging you :(

Comment: @VyshnaviReddy, your code will return a ListenableFuture GenericType Object, please see its explained doc https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained and its javadoc http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html to know how to use it and be sure the retrieving data.