# mclient.InvokeApi in java for android

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

How do I do the same functionality of retrieving data from a mobile service by invoking its method in java for a android app.

Below is the C# code I used for developing Windows application , now I want to the same for an android app

```
MobileServiceClient mobileservice = new MobileServiceClient("Azure mobile service api", "Application Key");

// Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
// dictionary.Add("oc_id", id);

var aod_return = await mobileservice.InvokeApiAsync("CCOOutageHistoryData", HttpMethod.Get, null); //dictionary);
List<Data> aod_result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(aod_return.ToString());
```

Please help me with the Java code and the appropriate constructor of InvokeApi for achieving this

The code I tried using in JAVA is

```
mClient = new MobileServiceClient( "Service API", "Key",this );   
mClient.invokeApi("CCOOutageHistoryData", null, "GET", null, new ApiJsonOperationCallback() { 
   @Override 
   public void onCompleted(JsonElement jsonElement, Exception e,   ServiceFilterResponse serviceFilterResponse) { 
      GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder(); 
      Gson gson = gsonb.create();
      JsonArray array = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
      List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
   }
});
```

Comment: What error do you get in your java code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the similar question with your another thread [Retrieve data from a azure mobile service into a android apllication in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464458/retrieve-data-from-a-azure-mobile-service-into-a-android-apllication-in-java/35476244#35476244) that I answered it.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.